# Alarm and Services - How to start alarm correctly

Tags: java, android

alarm contains the following vars

```
Day day;
int hour;
int minute;
boolean active;
SoundFile soundfile;
```

I added a Alarm Manager system & Service

```
 public void StartAlarm(Alarm alarm){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);

    if(c.before(Calendar.getInstance())){
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    //StartSong(alarm.soundfile); 
}
```

**Questions**

1. How should I start the alarms?
2. Where do make it check the following:

   - if the alarm is active
   - if the alarm's day is the correct day.
   - if it's time to go off.
3. Do I StartAlarm on every alarm right away with a delay in "setExact" or do I only "StartAlarm();" when I should set it off?
4. Follow up to question above: if I should set StartAlarm right away - how do I deal with/calculate the day difference between days.

Comment: You are using the alarm manager, right? If so, your app should start its activity from the alarm receiver and show all the required UI there.

Comment: I haven't added any alarm manager @PavelB. I have never used it, but I will look into it - thank you. Just used android studio a few days and have no experience with Java so there is tons ot learn

Comment: https://medium.com/@pedromassango/scheduling-tasks-using-alarmmanager-on-android-8672531b1609